# NAnt: get task permission denied

Tags: windows, permissions, nant

I'm trying to use the NAnt `<get>` task to download some artifacts from our build server.

However I'm getting permission denied to the destination folder even though the folder I'm downloading to has "Everyone" with full control.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind,

The problem was that in the destination of the `<get>` task you need to specify the file as well as the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Is the directory read-only? If so, you should be able to use the `<attrib>` task before `<get>` to allow read/write access temporarily.