# NAnt - Access to path is denied

Tags: continuous-integration, nant

Using NAnt, I'm attempting to download a file to a specific directory using the 'get' task.

I know I can copy files into the directory without issue, but when the task executes, I'm getting a message stating 'Access to the path '' is denied.

How can I get past this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a complete path on the 'get' tasks's 'dest' attribute. It expects the full path of the file at the destination rather than just the destination directory.

[Source (posted as a separate question for getting search results since I had to hunt for it for a while)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214364/nant-get-task-permission-denied)